What is the connection between the reason for eating matza, and the prohibition of chometz?
It is an explicit Torah Isur (prohibition) to eat (and own) chometz (leaven) during Passover, as stated in Exodus 13:7.
The explanation given for this in the Haggadah is because when the Jewish people were leaving Egypt there was not enough time for their dough to rise.
How does this reason also translate into a direct prohibition? What is the connection between the lack of dough rising and the Isur of chometz?

Are you asking what chametz has to do with risen bread? Or why we commemorate this specific thing that happened?

"The common explanation for this is because when the Jewish people were leaving Egypt there was not enough time for their dough to rise." What do you mean "common explanation"? It's explicit in the Haggadah!

I said "It's explicit in the Haggadah". It's more than that. It's an explicit verse (Devarim 16:3) in the Chumash: "לא תאכל עליו חמץ שבעת ימים תאכל עליו מצות לחם עני כי בחפזון יצאת מארץ מצרים למען תזכר את יום צאתך מארץ מצרים כל ימי חייך" (see Rashi there). (Thanks to @N.T. , for pointing it out.)

As the Haggadah states, the Matza is in order to remember the dough of our ancestors. Here's a story that is given on this:

A great King was touring his kingdom, when he happened upon a fair maiden, the daughter of a simple farmer. He fell madly in love and proposed marriage to her, and she and her father accepted. The King's love was insatiable, and he simply couldn't wait to be married to her. He badgered the royal staff day in day out to hurry up with their preparations for the wedding constantly.
Finally the day of the wedding arrives, and it's all going too slow. When sitting down for the wedding banquet, he's finally had enough. He runs into the kitchen and says "that's it, no more waiting, bring out the food!". The staff try to complain that the food is not ready, and the bread hasn't even risen yet". He isn't having any of it, and they bring out the food, and serve these flat, undone pieces of cracker instead of bread. The banquet proceeds and then they are married. The fair maiden, during the wedding, takes a couple of these crackers and keeps them safe.
It didn't take long, but soon they got into their first fight as husband and wife. During the fight, the King's anger is very great, and he yells at her "just remember that you were just a poor farmer's daughter, you are only here because of my good grace!". She storms off, but soon returns, bringing some of the crackers she kept from the wedding, and she shows them to him. She says "I may be a poor farmer's girl, but remember how you fell in love with me? Don't forget your love! Your love was so great, that you couldn't even wait an extra 20 minutes to marry me, and rushed through the wedding, and here are the crackers you had them serve us on that day".
Seeing the crackers indeed brought him back to his senses, and he remembered his great love for her, and they reconciled. Whenever the King was feeling the challenge of being married, she only had to bring out these "crackers", and he would remember his eternal love for her, and their marriage was a great success!

Now, in order to understand the point of the prohibition and its connection with the positive aspect, one must look at the pasuk, and the following pasuk, and the way the sages and the Haggadah explain what it's all about.
The following pasuk states

וְהִגַּדְתָּ לְבִנְךָ בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא לֵאמֹר בַּעֲבוּר זֶה עָשָׂה
יְהֹוָה לִי בְּצֵאתִי מִמִּצְרָיִם׃
And you shall tell over to your son on that day, saying, "Because of this Hashem did to me when I went out of Egypt"

We say this when the matza is in front of us, to say "because of this", i.e. because of the remembrance of the great love Hashem has for us1, and it must be personal - we must really view as though we personally were there, and experienced that great love, because indeed we did2:

לֹא אֶת־אֲבוֹתֵינוּ בִּלְבַד גָּאַל הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא, אֶלָּא
אַף אוֹתָנוּ גָּאַל עִמָּהֶם
It was not only our ancestors whom the Holy One redeemed; He redeemed
us too along with them

Therefore, because of the fact that we only had matza, and no leaven then, we must recreate this, and strengthen it, on Pesach. We must have matza, and no leaven, בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא
.

1. and how the Matza is a reminder of that for us; see Pele Yoetz 88:3; note also that this pasuk is invoked against the wicked son, to remind us of the reciprocal nature of this love; see Midrash Sekhel Tov, Shemot 13:8
2. בְּכָל־דּוֹר וָדוֹר, see Peninei Halakhah, Pesach 15:9

Love this. Chag sameach
